# Is there a cleaner way to check if an object is not false?

Tags: c#, syntax

Is there a cleaner way to write this?

```
if (!(obj is bool) || (bool)obj)
```

In PHP or JS you could write

```
if (obj !== false) // note the double == to indicate a type-check
```

It's just a little hard to read, and pretty syntactically ugly in C#.

---

To be absolutely clear, `obj` is an `object`.

Comment: You don't mean "check if an object is **not** false", or "check if an object is **true**", do you?

Comment: @BoltClock: Sorry, yes. I meant "check if an object is **not** false"

Comment: Why do you need to make a correct one-liner "cleaner?" Add a line or two of comment explaining why you have to do the explicit type checking. If you find that it's cumbersome because you're repeating it all over the place, then you're violating DRY.

Comment: @Kennet: A few reasons. As of now, it only occurs in one place, so yes, it's a one-liner. If there weren't any "nice" answers to this question, I would absolutely encapsulate the check into it's own function, but *because* I asked, I discovered that why yes, there is a pretty nice solution (thx Mehrdad) that is so concise and readable, that it doesn't really need to be encapsulated. Furthermore, I ask to learn, not to solve a very specific problem. Here I want to check if an object is not false, but the solutions here easily apply to any scenario where I have an object and want to check it--

Comment: --against a specific type and value. Also, I like *all* of my code to be clean, even the stuff that occurs only once. Sooner or later, I'll have to re-read it, or use it again in a different project... or whatever. And maybe I'm a bad person, but I don't like comments. I prefer readable code.

Comment: If you're calling this multiple times, you could consider putting @Mehrdad's answer in an extension method, and then simply call `if(!obj.isBoolFalse){...}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (!false.Equals(obj))  { ... }
```

<strike>Edit: Since I don't want @BoltClock to lose his eyesight, here's something that might be better:</strike>

```
if ((bool?)obj != false) { ... }
```

Edit 2: Don't try what I put above, because it won't work if `obj` is of a type other than `bool?` or `bool`.

Comment: Clever, although I now have to try to stop my eyes from bleeding seeing `!false` so they can see the `.Equals(obj)` attached to the `false` :)

Comment: @BoltClock: Oh sorry... [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Wash-Eyes-With-Water) might help then. ;)

Comment: Anyone using this code, disqualifies himself/herself as a serious C# programmer. IMNSHO, of course.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I could save my eyes by writing `true.Equals(obj)` instead. But that's just me :D

Comment: @BoltClock: Lol, yeah -- I just gave the OP what was asked for ("not `false`")... P.S.: Is the newer version better? :P

Comment: While this is syntactically correct, it is far from idiomatic.  We should be encouraging @Mark to write something that the rest of us will understand easily.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't think `if ((bool?) obj)` would work, you'd need the `!= false`. And related to that, I once wrote this just for kicks: `if (!((bool?) obj ?? false)) // if it's null or false`

Comment: @BoltClock: Whoops my bad, you're right... And haha nice! :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Your more boring solutions won't work. `obj` is not guaranteed to be a boolean, which is why I'm checking for "not false". Anything other than false should pass, including but not limited to `true`. First 2 solutions are nice though :)

Comment: @BoltClock: Come to think of it, although I just added it, would `true.Equals(obj)` even work? It returns `false` for `null` when the OP in fact wanted true...

Comment: @Mark: Haha yeah we just posted at the same time; corrected. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: In PHP and JS, `null !== false`, so it's OK.

Comment: @Lee: Do you have any better solutions?

Comment: As I stated in a different comment. This would be a good example of using this as an extension method `isBoolFalse`. Then you only have to write the ugly code once, and simply call `if(!obj.isBoolFalse){...}`

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: Is the `!false` really *that* bad? I had no problem with it, but you can always put a space, like `! false`, to make it more clear if your eyes are bleeding...

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm with you about this *not* needing an extension... but I was just trying out your 2nd solution... won't work if the object isn't null, true, or false. Invalid cast exception. I thought maybe if it wasn't a `bool?` it would default to `null`, but that's not the case.

Comment: @Mark: Ahh you're absolutely correct! I totally missed that; I'll edit it out. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: `!obj.Equals(false)` reads nicer I think, but I guess the real type could overwrite to give it an illogical meaning?

Comment: @Mehrdad, I personally just don't like `False.Equals(obj)` - Even though it's perfectly valid, it feels a little Yoda Code'ish. I would put it in an extension simply to keep it a little more logical long term. But again.. that's just me. I like the way @Marks reads and would use that, but as pointed out, it's not valid if `obj` is `null`.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: If not liking it be you, then create an extention method you absolutely may...

Comment: @Mehrdad Will `if (((obj as bool?) ?? false) != false)` work? `as` has the desired effect of resulting in `null` when it is not a `bool?`.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Yeah I think that works... the three question marks make me want to tear out my eyes though. It's as though the code is screaming, "Is it right?? Is it correct *now*?? **HOW ABOUT NOW**????"

Comment: @Sjoerd: `null` doesn't evaluate to a boolean, so I don't think you can throw that in an `if`, but you're on the right track. `if(obj as bool? != false)` is a pretty nice solution too.

Comment: @Mark: You could of course always do `!object.Equals(false, obj)` too, but that would require an additional boxing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Change your code such that the type of obj is `bool` and not `object`.

Somewhere in your code you converted your bool into an object. Why did you that? Find that place and keep it as a bool.

This is C# and not PHP or JS. C# is **strongly typed** - use that fact!

Comment: Really? There are many legitimate reasons to do what the OP is asking.

Comment: +1 - If you pass everything around as an `object` in C# as you would in PHP or JavaScript then of course the syntax is going to look ugly!

Comment: @Greg Are there? Since C# 2.0 and the introduction of generics, containers are type-safe as well. So it barely ever is needed to store a boolean as an object. And if it is, it's better to wrap the boxing/unboxing into a separate function or property, so it should never show up in an if.

Comment: Yes, if you only use code that you wrote yourself then don't pass things around as `object`. But not everything comes to you strongly typed when using external libraries or DataTable.

Comment: Yeah.... I'm pretty tempted to down-vote you. I used an object specifically because it could be anything. I'm writing a grammar and I'm storing key/value pairs, where the value can be of any type. If I could be more strict, I would be.

Comment: @Greg There are legitimate reasons but I wouldn't say there are *many* of them.

Comment: @Mark You should consider using Generics to allow for compile-time type safety checks.  Is it **really** valid for *anything* other than a `boolean` to pass through this code and have it silently return false?

Comment: @Kragen: Can't use generics here either. And it's not silently returning false, it's just doing something different. Booleans and `null` are special cases, everything else gets casted to a string... don't really want to go too in depth here.

Comment: @Mark I assume you have a class that does this casting to string and special-casing null and bool. I assume your check will appear in more than one place in your code as well. So I suggest adding an `bool isNotFalse(string key)` member to that class. And a `bool isBool(string key)`, `bool isNull(string key)` and so on. DRY, so do not copy-paste that one liner all over your code.

Comment: @Mark and if bool and null are the only special cases, why not use two containers? `Dict<string, string?>` (used for nulls as well), and `Dict<string, bool>`.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I'm big on DRY, but as of yet, this hasn't recurred anywhere else. `!false.Equals(obj)` isn't so bad that it needs to be encapsulated anyway.

Comment: @Sjoerd: `string` already allows `null`. `string?` doesn't exist. Those are the only special cases *for this method*, they may be treated differently in different places, and I don't want to make any assumptions or do pre-processing to sort them into different buckets. That's just needlessly complicating things. Actually, it just wouldn't work, because then I'd have to decide which dictionary I want to pass before I even call the function. Ugh. Plus I *want* all the values in that function, not just either-or.

Comment: @Mark About the `string?`: you're right. String is already a reference type, I forgot.

Comment: @Mark Just combine both dictionaries into one class and pass that. With the added benefit that you can add appropiate named members to add key/value pairs, and to check whether a key exists.

Comment: @Sjoerd: Added benefit that I can check if a key exists? Then I'd have to check 2 dicts instead of one. That isn't easier. I'm afraid your complicating things without any added benefit. It might make sense to split things up like that in some scenarios, but I'm fairly certain it isn't in mine.

Comment: @Mark In most cases you know in which dictionary to look as you'll cast it to either a string or a bool on the next line so there is no point to look in the other dictionary. Combine the look-up and cast into one member, and presto!

Comment: @Mark But I can't convince you, and you can't convince me, so let's keep it at that. You have a solution to your problem, while I've expressed my opinion that a more type-safe solution usually is better. Future viewers will see both opinions and can decide themselves what is the better option in their case.

Comment: No presto. You're telling me I now have to split my function in *two*, one that takes a `Dictionary<string,string>` and one that takes a `Dictionary<string,bool>` despite them acting *very* similar except for a minor difference. In that case, I'd actually have to write a 3rd function to encapsulate the commonalities. Also, it *still* wouldn't work, because *I want mixed types in my dictionary* as I keep saying. The function doesn't handle either/or, it handles *both*; you can't split them. And instead of writing `obj is bool`, I'd be writing `obj is in boolDict`... what's the benefit?

Answer (score 0):

try this, its easy to read and sometimes code needs to be ledgible..

```
if (obj.Equals(false))
```

Comment: Yes, that was the goal of this question, but as Mehrdad and I were discussing in the comments below his question, this is problematic if a) `obj` is `null` (which is valid in my case), or b) `obj` overrides `Equals` to do something stupid (unlikely but noteworthy)